# Start test container of ElasticSearch with plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch, testcontainers

I'm using testcontainers.org using `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.3.2` and I want to use it to test the plugin I'm updating, but I can't find a way to install it inside test environment.

I can try to copy file inside and install it

```
ElasticsearchContainer container = new ElasticsearchContainer("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:$ELASTIC_VERSION")
String pluginPath = "/usr/share/elasticsearch/$PLUGIN_FILE_NAME"
container.start()
container.copyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forHostPath(new File(PLUGIN_PLUGIN_PATH).toPath()), pluginPath)
ExecResult result = container.execInContainer("bin/elasticsearch-plugin", "install", "file://$pluginPath")
```

but then container is already started and elastic search is already running so plugin will not be loaded so I would need to kill it and replicate how it is created, sounds like a lot of hacking around. Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by using [Testcontainers Dockerfile DSL](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/creating_images/)

For example following code snippet works for me:

```
@ClassRule
public static GenericContainer elastic = new GenericContainer(new ImageFromDockerfile()
    .withDockerfileFromBuilder(
        builder -> builder.from("elasticsearch:6.8.4")
                          .run("bin/elasticsearch-plugin", "install", "analysis-icu")
                          .run("bin/elasticsearch-plugin", "install", "analysis-smartcn")
                          .build()
)).withExposedPorts(9200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to start an Elasticsearch test container with a plugin this way (it's a Kotlin code):

```
ElasticsearchContainer("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0").apply {
    withCreateContainerCmdModifier { cmd ->
        cmd.withCmd(
            *arrayOf(
                "bash",
                "-c",
                """/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install <URL> &&
                   su elasticsearch -s /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
                """.trimIndent()
            )
        )
    }
    start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
private static final String DOCKER_IMAGE = "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.5"
private static final ElasticsearchContainer container = new ElasticsearchContainer(DOCKER_IMAGE);

static {
    container.withCreateContainerCmdModifier((cmd) -> {
        cmd.withCmd(
            "bash", "-c", "./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu && docker-entrypoint.sh eswrapper");

    });
    container.withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
}


@BeforeClass
public static void start() {
    container.start();
}

@AfterClass
public static void stop() {
    container.stop();
}
```

please note that Elasticsearch version 6.8.5 in this example is old and you should probably use a newer one.